# How to direct API requests to /api/* and all other requests to S3 when using Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, cors, amazon-lightsail

I am using AWS and have a Rust API web server hosted on a Lightsail instance, and also my entire frontend's static assets (images, javascript, CSS) dumped into an S3 bucket. (It's a single page application)

I want all requests to `mysite.com/api/*` to be sent to my Lightsail instance, and all other requests to be sent to my S3 bucket.

I created a CloudFront distribution and made a CNAME that points my domain to it, but I'm having an issue because when AWS asks for the origin domain for the Lightsail instance, it refuses to accept its static IP address, saying that it needs a domain instead.

So in namecheap I made an `A record` that points `api.mysite.com` to my Lightsail instance's static IP so I could specify it as an origin domain for my CloudFront distribution, but now I'm getting cookie issues because the cookie's domain is being set to `api.mysite.com`.

I seem to be back at square one. Is there any way to avoid even having to use an A record here? I don't want to put my API on a subdomain. I just want it accessible from `mysite.com/api` Another issue is that now people can ping my site's `api.mysite.com` to find the API's IP address. The whole point to doing `mysite.com/api/*` was so I could avoid CORS, cookie issues, and having the server IP be visible.

Is there really not a way to just have a single domain `mysite.com` that just points to my CloudFront distribution while having /api/* requests go to Lightsail, and everything else going to my S3 bucket?